# Designing this algorithm a better way?

Tags: java, algorithm, ipc

I am working a much more complex version of this (with vehicle moving in both X and Y directions)

I made this example to get ideas on better ways to accomplish this.

1. I have a vehicle moving in the X direction at a speed (24.5872 mps)
2. I am simulating this by incrementing the X value every 100 ms using an executor (To keep its X position more accurate and real time)
3. After each second, I send a message to another process with the xMin and xMax values of the line I just covered
4. The other process will respond with a JMS message (usually instantly) telling me to stop if there was an "Pothole" in the previous X area (Message callback msg to a linkedblockingqueue).

The problem I have is with the "usually instantly" part.  If I do not get a response quick enough, I think it will throw off the whole timing of my algorithm.  What is a better way to handle this situation?

Here is some basic code of what I am trying to do:

```
public class Mover implements MessageHandler {

    private static final long CAR_UPDATE_RATE_IN_MS = 100;
    private static double currX = 0;
    private static double CONSTANT_SPEED_IN_MPS = 24.5872; // 55 mph
    private static double increment = CONSTANT_SPEED_IN_MPS / (1000 / CAR_UPDATE_RATE_IN_MS);
    static LinkedBlockingQueue<BaseMessage> messageQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<BaseMessage>(); // ms

    private static int incrementor = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        startMoverExecutor();
    }

    private static void startMoverExecutor() {

        ScheduledExecutorService mover = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        mover.scheduleAtFixedRate((new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                currX = incrementor * increment;

                if (incrementor % (1000 / CAR_UPDATE_RATE_IN_MS) == 0) {
                    System.out.println(currX);

                    sendMessage(currX - CONSTANT_SPEED_IN_MPS, currX);

                    // do something
                    try {
                        messageQueue.poll(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
                incrementor++;
            }

        }), 0, CAR_UPDATE_RATE_IN_MS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(BaseMessage msg) {
        messageQueue.add(msg);

    }

    protected static void sendMessage(double firstX, double secondX) {
        // sendMessage here

    }

}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a JMS message?

Comment: Here's a small speed-up in you code: change `currX = incrementor * increment;` to `currX += increment;` and set initialize currX as `currX = -increment;` Just changing a * to a +, but there you go.

Comment: @Justin I doubt that any imagined speed up will be measurable if it's doing IPC. Repeated addition will also cause larger errors to accumalate.

Comment: Two things: how important is consistency in your simulation? i.e. is it important that every run has the potholes in the same places or could you accept that your car "stops" randomly sometimes even if there is no pothole in its trajectory?

Also, how frequent is the delay in your experience? Or are you trying to optimize prematurely something that will work fast enough when complete?

Comment: I looked at the algorithm above (not your code). To achive this "usually instantly" part I have totally changed the algorithm (see my solution below).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am proposing changes to your algorithm above as shown in steps below.

**JMS Call to other process**

---

1a. Start with sending the current position of vehical.

1b. The other process will respond with a JMS message containing list of all the "Pot holes positions" in the visible area of your vehical's position. Keep this list of "visible pot holes positions" at client side for use in steps below.

1c. We define visible area as vehical's neighbouring area such that even with (1-second-delay + network-lag) of calling other process with JMS, movement of vehical should not cross this area.

1d. After each second, repeat steps 1a and 1b and replace list of pot holes positions at client side relative to current position of your vehical.

.

**Vehical movement observer**

---

2a. Implement an Observer pattern which can receive notifications of vehical movements.

2b. Each time event is generated, observer will make a check if vehical's position matches with one of the entry in list of visible pot holes acquired in step 1b.

2c. If match found, bingo! You got to stop the vehical.

.

**Vehical movement**

---

3a. Register step-2a observer to observe vehical's movements

3b. Wait until you have got atleast first list of visible pot holes from step 1b.

3c. Start moving the vehical by incrementing the X value every 100 ms. Each time it moves, it should notify the step-2a observer.

.

**Legends for below diagram:**

---

```
o - Instance of each pot hole somewhere on map 
X - Moving vehical
. - Path followed by vehical
Circle - Visible area of the vehical driver
```

```
+---------------------------------------------+
|                                             |
|                    o                o       |
|    o                                        |
|                                             |
|                                             |
|                _.-''''`-._                  |
|    o         ,'           `.             o  |
|            ,'  o            `.              |
|           .'    .            `.             |
|           |      . .          |             |
|           |         .         |   o         |
|           |         X         |             |
|   o       \                o  /             |
|            \                 /              |
|             `.             ,'               |
|               `-._     _.-'                 |
|                   `''''                     |
|                                             |
|                  o                          |
|                                    o        |
|                                             |
|                                             |
|     o                        o              |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 3):

Unless you're running the system on networks and operating systems that provide real-time guarantees, there *will* occasionally be delays. So you have to be able to detect those delays and decide how to respond - does time stop for your side of the simulation until the car finds out how the map is unrolling beneath it? or does time continue to flow but a late-notified pothole turns up further along the road than it would have? or is a late-arriving pothole detected as late and ignored?

I'm not too familiar with the current state of Java messaging. Can you clarify if `messageQueue.poll` is blocking? If you're sending a message and then blocking for an answer it raises the question of why you don't use something synchronous like a method call to a remote object, since that would definitely help the infrastructure in getting messages to you without delay.

Comment: poll is blocking... These requirements are not mine, but given to me.

Comment: You can still continue processing even if poll is blocking is what Donal is suggesting

Answer (score 2):

I would save the time of the currX computing along with the position (currX)

The next time you compute the currX, you look how much millisec elapse since the last time (System.currMillisec() - lastCalc), multiply that by the speed and add that to currX. Then set the last date of calculation to now.

edit:
- be careful with your unit (constant name: MPS, comment: mph)

add that to the declaration :

```
private static long compDate = System.currentTimeMillis();
private static long lastNotifDate = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

and the start of the run method:

```
currX += (System.currentTimeMillis() - compDate) * CONSTANT_SPEED_IN_MPS / 1000;
compDate = System.currentTimeMillis();

if (compDate - lastNotifDate > 1000) {
    lastNotifDate = System.currentTimeMillis();
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you don't need the code to run in real time, but just simulate it and calculate the real time values?

Comment: Hmmm... Actually, This does need to run in real time.. I am just part of a "simulation"... Our requirement is:  1 second of computer time is 1 second of clock time.

Comment: If it needs to be real-time, this is not possible using the standard JVM. Timing on the JVM is not predictable due to gc and also because the OS might not be real-time. You need to be running a real-time JVM like http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/realtime/index.jsp on a real-time operating system to guarantee this.

Comment: So long as you keep a count of the amount of time elapsed since the last simulation update, and always progress the simulation by that distance, the simulation will be in realtime. If you spend a second doing a garbage collection (GCs are actually really fast, so it's not really a worry) then the next time step will be a bit bigger and will "catch up" with realtime

Answer (score 1):

well, if this is an simulation, then you will not know ahead of any potholes.
my best bet so far is to move:

```
                // do something
                try {
                    messageQueue.poll(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }'
```

after or before this:

```
            if (incrementor % (1000 / CAR_UPDATE_RATE_IN_MS) == 0) {
            .. code ..
            }
```

and change argument in poll from 1000 to 1 (or 0 if this means that poll will not wait , but quit immidiately)

Comment: +1 just use messageQueue.poll() which returns immediately if there is no message waiting.

Answer (score 1):

As you say,

> The problem I have is with the "usually instantly" part. If I do not get a response quick enough, I think it will throw off the whole timing of my algorithm. What is a better way to handle this situation?

In an ideal world your computer's clock is perfect, garbage collection is atomic, instantaneous and in O(1), networks have no delay, OS have no interrupts and Murphy is sound asleep.

Since you are dealing with a real-world situation, you need to adjust for the uncertainty typical of it. First, you need **statistics**. Surely Java GC is never guaranteed to be real-time, but you can have a fairly good approximation that works 90% of the time. The remaining 10% can be handled by another 'plan B', so on and so forth.

In other words: run your system and try to hinder it as much as you can; collect usage statistics; work on the best workarounds for those circumstances. For example,

- insert random delays in your simulation's simulation and see how it responds (**unit test**!); perhaps you want to run the run() method every 500ms?
- use an observer pattern (as suggested elsewhere);
- have as little code as possible run in the run() method; perhaps run it every `1sec - epsilon`, where *epsilon* is a small enough interval that accounts for the delay with the highest variance in a large enough sample
- have two separate threads run simultaneously, keep them in sync using a lock, average their running time to get a better clock

In a pinch, there's no exact solution as there is no exact 'real' world. Add noise, get ready for the worse, average out the rest.

Answer (score 1):

The grain size of the collision detection space seems to me to be too small to depend on JMS reliably.

I would change this so that *Mover* receives a reasonable chunk of the map that it can use locally, e.g. if the entire map is 100 x 100, then *Mover* should receive at least a 10 x 10 portion of the grid.

This portion of the grid can be interrogated locally for potholes at every move, and when the location gets close to a boundary of the 10 x 10 portion, then the next square can be requested.

This will give you a kind of double-buffer window, where the new square can be loaded while the remaining moves continue to be evaluated against the old square.

In addition, you may want to be able to listen for changes to squares, so that when someone adds a new pothole to a square that has previously been loaded, then that new square will be broadcast and any clients that have that square currently loaded can reload it.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Have computer B send back the location of the pothole when it detects one, then computer A can  move the vehicle to this position. If the vehicle on computer A does something other than just sit there when it has hit the pothole then perhaps this article will help you reduce a sudden change in position/direction/velocity:
http://www.gamedev.net/reference/programming/features/cubicsplines/

- Computer A: The computer that's
  sending it's position
- Computer B: The
  computer that checks for potholes

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be possible to use **Concurrency** or some **Read-ahead** technique? 
I mean your problem is waiting on the messageQueue. If you could Async it, wouldn't it help? Perhaps use callback?
You could perhaps save the state when a call is made to Process B and continue Process A. If Process B replies with some error, then stop and revert state to saved values.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have much experience with discrete event simulation?  The concept is that you schedule events in advance on a calendar, keep track of the time those events occur in a list, and update the state of the system upon arrival at any giving event with a set of rules. Rather than worrying about the time required to run a called subroutine, you effectively schedule the future in a list.  Does this make sense?  Let me know if you need more info / references.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly use Observer rather than message passing for quick response?

Comment: JMS is required... I am party of a larger system where messages are being used

Answer (score 0):

I would say the biggest change that should be made is --

Remove the asynchronous communication ie JMS and put some synchronous communication mechanism.

That could be an RPC call/ WebService Call.

**---Update---**

Just saw your comment that you can not remove the JMS part being a party to a much larger system.

Then we will have to accept that we cannot take decision until the JMS message has not arrived. Probably, there is very little that could be done in this scenario...

Answer (score 0):

Achieving almost instant message delivery with JMS is going to be a tough one here. Basically JMS was designed with more focus on delivery guarantee than the speed of delivery.

[Here](http://www.javaperformancetuning.com/tips/j2ee_jms.shtml#REF5) are some points which may help you speed up your JMS deliveries but in JMS world one can only guarantee delivery and not speed.

I cannot help but mention that you should also consider a caching solution. I got a nice [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326747/need-a-cache-which-is-shared-between-c-java-and-net-applications) for this type of cache for one of my questions on SO. ....And it rocks!